# Is it possible to meassure anxiety/stress via data collected from smart watches for a whole region?

Tags: stress, data, technology, pulse

A lot of people wear smart watches and other fitness trackers these days. All of which measure at least the wearers pulse, usually a lot more data – even automatically recognizing type of exercise. Some claim to analyze stress levels directly.

The measured data is usually stored on servers of the manufacturer and does provide a large amount of data about individuals across regions, even whole countries.

I know that analysis of data like this is common practice in other fields. However, I’m unsure if the available data from the fitness trackers could provide clear enough pattern for any usable results.

**Data access issues aside**, to examine the concept of the idea, can the pulse histogram data (for example, of a large amount of people) be used to identify stress and anxiety changes – possibly correlated with events in the given region to analyze their impact?

Comment: Welcome to this community! I recommend doing another round of proofreading since there's a few typos here. Also, it's an individual that wheres a watch and has a biological pulse, not a country, so perhaps you can ask if a smartwatch can measure an individual's anxiety, then extrapolate yourself about *trends* in a larger population of people with smartwatch data.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, that the focus of the question was not clear enough, will edit it.

Comment: @bennn it's actually a fascinating research question and a great first question by a new user. As comments point out it needed some polish, and honestly sometimes people reflexively downvote question that are simply out of the ordinary, so don't worry about those. There are [almost 200 Stack Exchange sites to choose from](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) and one that you might find helpful is [Open Data SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/), for example [Location-based sleep dataset](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/15687/21170) though it's currently unanswered. I'll give it a bump

Comment: This has three answers: [What quantified self products have open data behind them?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/295/21170) and asks about "anonymized sleep quality logs" which I think might be something of interest. Also, for an unusual question I've found that what works best is to ask a first question "Has X been done?" or "How best to search for work doing X?". Based on the answers or lack thereof to that question, I would formulate a second, new question days or weeks later "There's not much work in X due to Y; how to approach it differently?" or similar.

Comment: But "Is X possible?" is a bad form for an SE question because it's really hard to say something is *impossible*. It's better to paint the topic with the "Has X been done?" or "Most likely challenges to doing X?" variety of questions that can have fact-based answers drawn from sources, but not "How *best* to do X?" because there will be a chorus of "How do you define best?" comments and associated "Voting to close as likely to attract primarily opinion-based answers" votes.

Comment: This question lacks prior research. Do those devices actually measure stress and do so accurately? Without knowing the answer to that question the only possible answer to this one is "maybe." So you need to find evidence (or lack thereof) that those devices can actually measure stress and add it to your question.

Comment: As @CareyGregory points out, **data access issues aside, which I'm not convinced is part of your question**, while you have a basis for a good question, there doesn't seem to be enough prior research. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Smart watches do measure a fair bit of data that could indicate stress, but do you know their accuracy for blood pressure readings, etc.? Look into that, bring it to the question, and it will be an excellent question.

Comment: @IanCampbell - while elements of the question would involve data access issues, I am not convinced it is in the main part of the question being asked. It is asked whether smart watch data could measure/indicate anxiety/stress levels.

Comment: @bennn - I have taken the liberty to edit your question to frame the question more around the concept of the idea to prevent closure by the community, maybe due to misreading the focus of the question? As well as dealing with the prior research issues, please feel free to make any further edits or roll it back to your previous version. **Be mindful that your question could still be closed for lack of prior research**

Comment: @ChrisRogers I agree that your edit (and to a large extent the question author's previous edit) addressed many of the data access concerns. However, it is still off topic due to lack of research (as you note) and potentially due to lack of focus.

Comment: @bennn Although you have an upvoted answer to your question, it still lacks prior research. Demonstrating some effort at finding out if wearable devices can detect stress is all we ask. You can [edit] your question to add such information and then it can be considered for reopening.

Answer (score 3):

[Tiwari et al, 2019](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8857890) found poor sensitivity and specificity for detecting stress using multiple features from a fitness watch: sensitivity 0.53, specificity 0.56, and similarly poor for anxiety: sensitivity 0.44, specificity 0.63.

Of course, this measures stress/anxiety in *individuals*, which is not quite the same as measuring it in *populations*.

I did not find any study that attempted to do what you describe: estimate population levels of stress or anxiety and correlate this to events, but probably the first step would be to do a validation against some gold-standard assessment.

In research and publishing it's not so much about what is *possible*, which seems to be a binary "yes it is possible" versus "no it is not possible", and more about *impact* of a given result. If you show a correlation, will people believe it? They're probably more likely to believe results that confirm their prior expectations, and disbelieve results that oppose them. For a measurement modality without a track record of success, that's the correct behavior. With more use and more evidence that a given measurement accurately reflects reality, people will begin to trust those results more than their preconceived ideas. I don't think this is something you can know or predict without having actually done the research.

---

Tiwari, A., Cassani, R., Narayanan, S., & Falk, T. H. (2019, July). A comparative study of stress and anxiety estimation in ecological settings using a smart-shirt and a smart-bracelet. In 2019 41st Annual International Conference of the IEEE Engineering in Medicine and Biology Society (EMBC) (pp. 2213-2216). IEEE.